# SQL Server : count distinct every 30 minutes or more

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime, aggregate-functions

We have an activity database that records user interaction to a website, storing a log that includes values such as `Time1`, `session_id` and `customer_id` e.g.

```
2022-05-12 08:00:00|11|1
2022-05-12 08:20:00|11|1
2022-05-12 08:30:01|11|1
2022-05-12 08:14:00|22|2
2022-05-12 08:18:00|22|2
2022-05-12 08:16:00|33|1
2022-05-12 08:50:00|33|1
```

I need to have two separate queries:

**Query #1:** I need to count sessions multiple times if they have a log of 30 minutes or more grouping them on sessions on daily basis.

For example: Initially count=0

- For session_id = 11, it starts at 08:00 and the last time with the same session_id is 08:30 -- count=1
- For session_id = 22 it starts at 08:14 and the last time with the same session is 08:14 -- still the count=1 since it was less than 30 min

I tried this query, but it didn't work

```
select 
    count(session_id)
from
    table1 
where 
    @datetime between Time1 and dateadd(minute, 30, Time1);
```

Expected result:

[image]

**Query #2:** it's an extension of the above query where I need the unique customers on daily basis whose sessions were 30 min or more.

For example: from the above table I will have two unique customers on May 8th

Expected result

[image]

For the Time1 column, the input is in timestamp format when I show it in output I will group it on a basis.

Comment: Expected results will help us help you here. Note, as well, that questions should only be asking 1 question; you appear to be asking 2 here.

Comment: Added expected results, since they are almost similar and from the same table, I put two questions.

Comment: Comments aren't twitter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a two-level aggregation (GROUP BY) problem. You need to start with a subquery to get the first and last timestamp of each session.

```
             SELECT MIN(Time1) start_time,
                    MAX(Time1) end_time,
                    session_id, customer_id
               FROM table1
              GROUP BY session_id, customer_id
```

Next you need to use the subquery like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(session_id),
       COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id),
       CAST(start_time AS DATE)
  FROM (
             SELECT MIN(Time1) start_time,
                    MAX(Time1) end_time,
                    session_id, customer_id
               FROM table1
              GROUP BY session_id, customer_id
       ) a
 WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, start_time, end_time) >= 30
 GROUP BY CAST(start_time AS DATE);
```